# Regex - Grab characters between two characters but not including them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to grab the rsession variable in the string below between '=' and '&' in a string.

I'm able to do it with `/rsession(\=.+?\&)/`.

But how do I do it so the output doesn't include the '=' and '&'?

The string is:
`"app=1334300&rsession=0806343413_1:5bc6a3c80271826a1c0016c1520d3&token=a6caacf7edfbd9383429e30a1adfadf385208985ad&redirectReq=true"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/(?<=rsession=)[^&]*/
```

Explanation:

```
(?<=              # asserts the match at position after
    rsession=     # the literal string `rsession=`
)                 # it is called: positive lookbehind
[^&]              # not `&` character
*                 # as many as possible
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I may correct you. `*` stands for `0` or `1`. Though it doesn't makes a difference here because session id will definitely be more than `1`.

Comment: @AndyPotter. Glad to hear that ;) ...  If this answer worked for you, you can accept it checking the [green mark](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/318874).

Comment: @noob. Yeah, no difference at all, but also allow empty text

Answer (score 0):

You can capture it in group like this.

**Regex:** `/rsession=([^&]+)/`

**Explanation:**

- `([^&]+)` will capture in group all characters until a `&` is met. Use `\1` or `$1` to use captured group.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rE4aE8/1)**

Comment: This still contains "rsession=" in what it captures.

Comment: @AndyPotter: As you mentioned `rsession` in your regex I thought you want to capture that too.`"/rsession(\=.+?\&)/"`. You can still use the **captured group**. That will still have only **session ID**.